# xcode interaction with a html website

Tags: html, xcode, macos, cocoa

I would like write a small program, which send a string to a Website und get the answer string back.

It's about the following site: http://www.pandorabots.com/pandora/talk?botid=ec8b3be33e34bf73

1. Programm send string to the text field on the website "Frage: ..."
2. Programm get back the string after "Brother B!:"

It is a cocoa application for OS X.

```
-(BOOL)getStringFromWebView:(NSString*)frage
{

//----------------Put the question (frage) into the text field on the web page

    if (frage.length != 0) {
        //create js strings
        NSString *loadUsernameJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='text']\"); \
            for (var i = inputFields.length >>> 0; i--;) { inputFields[i].value = '%@';}", frage];
        //autofill the form
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: loadUsernameJS];
    }

    //-------------Press 'return' to send the message 
    //PROBLEM: Webview is not active. It do not work...

    CGEventRef push = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, 0x24, true);
    CGEventRef release = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, 0x24, false);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, push);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, release);

    //I tried this to focus the web view:
    //[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"input\").setFocus();"];


    //----------get response from web page (work!):

    WebFrame *frame = [self.webView mainFrame];
    WebDataSource *source = [frame dataSource];
    NSData *data = [source data];
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   // NSLog(@"%@",str);
    NSArray *woerter1 = [str componentsSeparatedByString: @"<I>Brother B!</I>: "];
    NSArray *woerter2 = [woerter1[1] componentsSeparatedByString: @"<form method=\"POST\">"];

    self.out3.stringValue = woerter2[0];

 return true;
}
```

Actually i don't really know how to do this... Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

you can load your web page in WebView/IUWebView object and interact with it by JavaScript bridge library. You can use this library [link](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge) to send to JavaScript a message from native application.

Next you can use JavaScript at html-client-side to manage this message and execute the form.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you! But im not sure how could i do that? Could you give me the code for that?

Comment: @Peter what is the problem? The UIWebView object or the bridge between UIWebView and JavaScript?

Comment: bridge between UIWebView and JavaScript. How could i do that?

Comment: Hi @Peter you can find a complete examples (iOS and OSX both) on GitHub repository at https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge/tree/master/Example%20Apps. Try i! :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! But i tried it out and it doesn't work... I don't know how this bridge is working. Is there any tutorial for that?

Comment: Please add your source code - example to your question